# Adobe Flash редактор

Tags: flash, редактор

Возможно в редакторе Adobe Flash конвертировать картинку для её последующего редактирования ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Для экспорта (и редактирования в другом редакторе) - File -> Export (выбрать растровый формат).
- Для импорта (и редактирования внутри Flash CS) - File -> Import.
- Для конвертации растра в вектор и редактирования (внутри Flash CS) - Edit -> Bitmaps -> Trace Bitmap.

(Так как направление конвертации не указано в вопросе **(!)** - указаны возможные навскидку.)

Comment: У меня есть картинка. Мне нужно перекинуть её в AF CS4 для редактирования, но если проще, перевести её в векторную графику. Не могу найти Edit -> Bitmaps -> Trace Bitmap.

Comment: Все нашел, спасибо.